# Match whole words in utf

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace all occurrences of `a` with `5`. Here is the code that works well:

```
$content=preg_replace("/\ba\b/","5", $content);
```

unless I have words like `zapłać` where `a` is between non standard characters, or `zmarła` where there is a Unicode (or non-ASCII) letter followed by `a` at the end of word. Is there any easy way to fix it?

Comment: I dont know how it should work with a single regex, but probably you could parse your result through the PHP function `mb_detect_encoding()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: The encoding isn't the problem.  The OP was using the word "utf" to mean a Unicode letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that the predefined character class `\w` is ASCII based and that does not change, when the `u` modifier is used. (See [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), preg is PCRE in the columns)

You can use [lookbehind and lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to do it:

```
$content=preg_replace("/(?<!\p{L})a(?!\p{L})/","5",$content);
```

This will replace "a" if there is not a letter before and not a letter ahead.

`\p{L}`: [any kind of letter from any language](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop).

Answer (score 0):

```
$content=preg_replace("/\ba\b/u","5",$content);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, `preg_replace("/\ba\b/u","5","A cat is øaå string");` is equal to `A cat is ø5å string`

Comment: This is not working, `\b` is ASCII based and this does not change, when the `u` modifier is added.